vmlinuz to vmlinux ERROR
$ file vmlinuz
vmlinuz: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 4.14.244 (root@d0ea4514eda5) #1 SMP Thu Aug 31 01:23:02 PDT 2023, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x3, Normal VGA

I try to use extract_vmlinux and vmlinux-to-elf to extract vmlinux from vmlinuz, but  report the following errors respectively:
$ vmlinux-to-elf vmlinuz vmlinux
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/vmlinux-to-elf", line 63, in <module>
    ElfSymbolizer(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/vmlinux_to_elf/elf_symbolizer.py", line 44, in __init__
    kallsyms_finder = KallsymsFinder(file_contents, bit_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/vmlinux_to_elf/kallsyms_finder.py", line 177, in __init__
    self.find_linux_kernel_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/vmlinux_to_elf/kallsyms_finder.py", line 225, in find_linux_kernel_version
    raise ValueError('No version string found in this kernel')
ValueError: No version string found in this kernel

$ ./extract_vmlinux vmlinuz > vmlinux
extract_vmlinux: Cannot find vmlinux.

Then I tried manual extraction:
$ od -A d -t x1 vmlinuz | grep 'fd 37 7a 58 5a 00'
3254032 fd 37 7a 58 5a 00 44 65 73 74 69 6e 61 74 69 6f

$ dd if=vmlinuz of=vmlinuz_unxz bs=1 skip=3254032
116928+0 records in
116928+0 records out
116928 bytes (117 kB, 114 KiB) copied, 1.10249 s, 106 kB/s

$ xz -d vmlinuz_unxz
xz: vmlinuz_unxz: Compressed data is corrupt

What went wrong? Any suggestions to extract vmlinux?
Thank you!

vmlinuz is bootable as is, it doesn't need extraction.  Why are you trying to "extract" it?  This smells like an XY problem.
